# azure search: same query on portal returns data, through .net sdk don't

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

Passing my search text as:

```
(Email: /.*jackson.*/)&(Postcode: /.*jackson.*/)&(FirstName: /.*jackson.*/)&(LastName: /.*jackson.*/)&(City: /.*jackson.*/)&(Answers: /.*jackson.*/)
```

and my Search Parameters as:

```
$count=true&$filter=Status%20ne%20'i'&$orderby=SubmittedDate desc&queryType=full&searchMode=all&$skip=0&$top=10
```

I get results using Search Explorer on Azure Portal. But using .NET SDK and passing the same values, it's not returning any row. Is there a way to get the query that is being sent to Azure Search? Also, to use multiple Lucene query fields, the '&' is the right operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see both the request sent by the SDK as well as the raw response.

To the Lucene syntax, you can scope to multiple fields by just separating the terms by a space. For example, `Email: /.*jackson.*/ Postcode: /.*jackson.*/` should work.  You can add logical operators as needed, but should not be required.

Hope this helps.

Mike